# Is it wrong to define a macro for printf?

Tags: c

I'm asking this for general knowledge purposes.

Can I define `printf` in a header file and use `pf` to replace `printf` throughout the whole program?

Is it wrong based on any standards?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define pf printf   //printf defined here

int main(){
    int x=10;
    pf("x=%d",x);  //pf is used instead of printf
}
```

PS: Learning new things just to get ahead in my class ;)

Comment: You can, unless `pf` is another function.

Comment: Your comment is wrong.  You are defining 'pf', not 'printf'.

Comment: Its 'wrong' based on the fact that it makes it harder to read without really doing anything

Comment: @TimCastelijns didn't get you bro :(

Comment: @WilliamPursell yeah! yeah! will change that :)

Comment: @user3389315 Others who read your code will see `pf(blabla)` and think ehhh pf? what is that, and then go to see that you defined it to replace printf. That it what i meant by making it harder to read. By saying it doesnt really do anything i meant that it literally has no use, typing pf isnt even faster than typing printf

Comment: There is a belief amongst C programmers that they only have so many keystrokes in them before they die. Do you share this belief?

Comment: @EricLippert hahaha :D nothing like that bro :)

Comment: I've updated your title. First, it's `printf`, not `Printf`; since C identifiers are case-sensitive, you shouldn't capitalize them. Second, your macro isn't in a header. (`<stdio.h>` is a header; the top of your source file is just the top of your source file.)

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks for updating :-) sorry i don't know the terminology in C :) $NewBie :-) and i think every written before `int main()`  are known as they declared in header. right ?

Comment: @user3389315: The term "header" is used specifically to refer to the file referred to in a `#include` directive. Calling the first few lines of a C source file a "header" makes sense, but because of the established meaning of the word it can be confusing.

Comment: @KeithThompson +1up :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's perfectly legal -- and horribly bad style.

The compiler will replace each occurrence of the identifier `pf` by `printf`.

But writing `printf` in full each time you use it makes your code much more readable to a human reader. If I see a call to `printf`, I know exactly what it means. If I see a call to something called `pf`, my first assumption will be that you have a function by that name, and I need to find out what it does. I have to hunt for you macro definition before I can understand what the call means. It wastes far more time than the 4 keystrokes you save by using a macro.

Comment: On the flip side, using a macro makes it possible to easily substitute something else for `printf`, especially on compilers that support __VARARGS__.  If it's necessary to replace `pf(...)` with `fprintf(stderr,...)` but there are other instances of `printf` that shouldn't be changed, using a macro for `pf` may be better than using `printf` everywhere.